# How to add a stock availabilty and sku next to price of the product on product page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sku, product-page, stock-availability

How to add a stock availabilty and sku next to price of the product on product page in magento 2 ?
Please answer this briefly because i am new in magento 2.
Also do we have to create a particular directory/structure for that?
Or we need to add the functionality in our code where this price attribute is already created?
Which js we gonna need to complete this task?
Anyone who will answer this please add the pictures and marks on them so that it will look easy and understandable to everyone.
Do we need admin for this task?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the stock availability for **InStock** and **OutOfStock** purpose then you can set the following configuration settings

**Magento Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options -> Set yes to "Manage Stocks"**

or

If you want to show the out of stock product then you can follow below step
**Stores > Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Stock Options**

Set **"yes"** in both the following fields:

- Display Out of Stock Products
- Display Products Availability in Stock
  on StoreFront

Now if you want to show the **SKU** then add the following code in your phtml file

To set this value in your phtml (**In your theme template**) then follow the below path **Magento_Catalog/view/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml**

To override in custom module then add the below code  **{Vendor_Module}/view/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml**

Make sure this code exists in a file :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView */?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>


<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()) :?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
        <div class="stock available" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php else :?>
        <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And add this code to **SKU**:

```
<?php echo  $_product->getSku(); ?>
```